# how to untar file in linux red hat?

Tags: rhel, kernel, linux-kernel, compiling, tar

I am compiling linux red hat stable kernel on red hat linux and the error which I am facing is as below [image: how should I remove this error]

Comment: @Nauman Sohail, Welcome to the site, use code instead of picture, picture is not earchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install XZ

```
yum -y install xz
```

then

```
tar -xvf yourfile.tar.xz
```

Comment: It's Wrong user have to use `-Jxf file.tar.xz`

Comment: On slackware 14.1i use tar -xvf without problem,same thing on centos6.6

Answer (score 1):

Should work with the following command:

```
tar -xvfz linux-2.6.32.65.tar.xz
```

Comment: If its a modern GNU tar, just leave off the decompression algorithm, and just use `tar xvf linux-2.6.32.65.tar.xz`.  Tar is smart enough to figure it out.